# Can I use MOQ to mock future instances?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I am new to unit testing and trying to figure out a bit more about MOQ.

Is there an API that allows me to mock future instances of some type?
I mean,
Let's say I am mocking a class. Inside that class I use the new operator to create a new instance of an object.
I want to mock all future instances of the same type of that object that will be created within that class in the future, is there such API?

I tried to look into MOQ documentation but there is no such example. Help anyone?

Comment: JustMock by Telerik does that, but it's part of their paid portion of JustMock. I can't speak to any other mocking suites, just wanted to toss that out there for you to look at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `new`, use dependency injection and a factory. Then you can make your class create mocks:

```
internal class SubjectUnderTest
{
    public SubjectUnderTest( IProductFactory factory )
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    public void DoStuff()
    {
        var product = _factory.CreateProduct(); // this creates a mocked product (where you new'ed something before)
        product.DoSomeThing(); // this calls into the mock product
    }

    private readonly IProductFactory _factory;
}
```

A test would then look like this

```
var mockFactory = new Mock<IProductFactory>();
mockFactory.Setup( x => x.CreateProduct() ).Returns( () => 
{
    var mockProduct = new Mock<IProduct>();
    // TODO setup product mock here
    return mockProduct.Object;
} );
var instance = new SubjectUnderTest( mockFactory.Object );
instance.DoStuff(); // <- uses the factory mock defined above to create a mocked product and calls into the mocked product
```